# Jmeter Run SQL script from file

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, jmeter

I am trying to run a couple SQL scripts in a Jmeter SetUp thread. Is it possible to run the SQL code from a .SQL file through Jmeter so I can initialize a database before my other threads get executed. I just don't want to break my code up and copy/paste code inside Jmeter using JDBC connection and JDBC request. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function seems to be something you're looking for, you can put it inside your [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler and specify path to your .sql file there like:

[image: JMeter JDBC From File]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to get familiarized with the JMeter Functions concept