# Jmeter java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550

Tags: jdbc, plsql, jmeter

I have a simple Jmeter script that needs to execute an SQL file to insert records into a database. I was trying to find a way for Jmeter to run the entire script using the following solution: [Jmeter Run SQL script from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464709/jmeter-run-sql-script-from-file)

My Test Plan is set-up just like the one in the above example. Here is the code inside my `setup.sql` file:

```
begin
  insert into DATA_STORE (ID, T_ID, SUB_T_ID, RESOURCE_TYPE_ID) values (283748, 'default', 'default', 10, 30, 'SM-CR-4GD73U82N273V4H4J4JI2J');
  insert into DATA_STORE (ID, T_ID, SUB_T_ID, RESOURCE_TYPE_ID) values (348393, 'default', 'default', 20, 50, 'SM-CV-64HF83H2WB273TBH372HJ2');
 COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Note: The insert statements work inside of SQL Developer and the values I used are arbitrary. This was just to give an example of how I want to have multiple statements inside this block to be executed from **one** file.

When I run this, I get the following error in Jmeter:

> Response code: 65000 6550
>
> Response message: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
>
> PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
>
> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
>
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" The symbol "/" was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `Query type` as `Update Statement`

Remove `/` character and add keyword `values` to your script :

```
begin
  insert into DATA_STORE values (ID, T_ID, SUB_T_ID, RESOURCE_TYPE_ID) values (283748, 'default', 'default', 10, 30, 'SM-CR-4GD73U82N273V4H4J4JI2J');
  insert into DATA_STORE values (ID, T_ID, SUB_T_ID, RESOURCE_TYPE_ID) values (348393, 'default', 'default', 20, 50, 'SM-CV-64HF83H2WB273TBH372HJ2');

 COMMIT;
END;
```